# Convergence of $\frac{n^{\ln n}}{(\ln n)^{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $$U_n = \frac{n^{\ln n}}{(\ln n)^{n}}$$

Does the series  $\sum Un$ converge ?

I've tried to do the convergence test, by seeing if $\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}$ converges to any real number $k$ with $k < 1$

Therefore I've transformed $\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}$ into
$$\frac{ \exp (\ln^2(n+1) + n\ln(\ln n)) }{ \exp(\ln^2(n) + (n+1)\ln(\ln (n+1))) }$$

this seems pretty messy and I don't know whether I'm doing it right.
Any help?

Comment: Use exponent representation and root test.

Comment: What you have is fine. It looks a little messy, but you can now use the fact that $\frac{x^a}{x^b}=x^{a-b}$. From here, you can clean things up pretty nicely (there is still some work to be done but compared to what you have done, I would say you have handled the hardest part already).

Comment: @Clayton that's what I was going to do before posting this, but wanted to know if there was a cleaner way. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If suffices to show that

$${n^{\ln n}\over(\ln n)^n}\lt{1\over n^2}$$

for all sufficiently large $n$, i.e., that $n^{\ln n+2}\lt(\ln n)^n$ for all large $n$. But this follows from the observation that

$$(\ln n+2)\ln n\lt2(\ln n)^2\lt n\lt n\ln\ln n$$

for large $n$; the first inequality in the display starts at $n=8$, the second at $n=14$, and the third at $n=16$.

Comment: seems like the easiest way to me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\frac{n^{\ln n}}{(\ln n)^{n}}=e^{\ln^2n-n\ln(\ln n)}$$

with

$$\frac{\ln^2n-n\ln(\ln n)}n\to -\infty$$

Comment: That’s not really enough. You need some growth estimate on the argument in the exponential.

Comment: $-\ln n \to -\infty$ but $\sum e^{-\ln n}$ diverges.

Comment: I agree with @Mindlack ... Correct me if I'm wrong, but I've been taught that proving that $Un$ converges to $0$ only gives it a "chance" to converge. It's not a proof of convergence.

Comment: Yes the previous hint was indeed not really helpful to conclude easily for the convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can write

$$
\frac{n^{ln(n)}}{(ln(n))^{n}}=\frac{(e^{ln(n)})^{ln(n)}}{(ln(n))^{n}}=\frac{e^{ln^{2}(n)}}{(ln(n))^{n}}
$$

We apply the root test

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]\frac{n^{ln(n)}}{(ln(n))^{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^{\frac{ln^{2}(n)}{n}}}{ln(n)}
$$

For a sufficiently large n is satisfied

$$
0 \leqslant \frac{e^{\frac{ln^{2}(n)}{n}}}{ln(n)} \leqslant \frac{1}{ln(n)}
$$

Finally, by the compression theorem

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}0 \leqslant \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{\frac{ln^{2}(n)}{n}}}{ln(n)} \leqslant \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{ln(n)}
$$

$$
0 \leqslant \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{\frac{ln^{2}(n)}{n}}}{ln(n)} \leqslant 0
$$

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{\frac{ln^{2}(n)}{n}}}{ln(n)} = 0
$$

Therefore the series converges

Answer (score 0):

I added it here, because, may be last change not being noted.
$$n\ln\ln n - \ln^2 n-=n\ln\ln n\cdot\left(1-\frac{\ln^2n}{n\ln\ln n}\right)\sim n\ln\ln n$$
as $e^f=(e^{g})^\frac{f}{g}$, then if root test is correct for $e^g$, then it will be correct for $e^f$ also, so we can use equivalence for exponent also.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net. It is equivalence I tried to explain.